# How to make this execute only once keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
$(".area").on("keyup", function(){
    this.style.height = "1px";
    var buttons_matrix =  (25 + this.scrollHeight) + "px";
    var p = $( "#butons_matrix" ).css('top',  buttons_matrix);   
});
```

How can I make it as soon as the class area is used once don't repeat it again the height, I can't use id here

Comment: Use `.one()` instead of `.on()`

Comment: As per @Mohammad's comment: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: You can use `off()` function of jQuery inside of the handler. e.g. `$(".area").off("keyup")` or `$(this).off("keyup")` when you need to disable only the element, not all classes.

Comment: .one() does not work

Comment: @lilo Check console for any error also write `alert()` in `.one()` to detecting  your code is correct.

Comment: Yea but I don't mean only one key after typing I ment, when I use this class area, when i start typing on onther text area field that has this class .area don't repeat the same process  because it returns the height smaller than it increases

Comment: @lilo As I understood, you wan't to work code for special element has `.area` not for all `.area`?

Comment: Or something like always take the biggest height and start from there

Comment: You can get biggest height using `Math.max.apply(Math, $(".area").map(function(){return $(this).height()}).toArray())`

Comment: I am sorry I am new on coding, how can i implement this on my code can you help me

Comment: @lilo Please share full html code in http://jsfiddle.net to better understanding

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yllbb/rm0xnscp/ here you have it but css is not good

Comment: @lilo But i can't see `.area` in shared html?